# how to get index of selected item in mat autocomplete?

Tags: angular-material

Is there any events for mat-option which is used for mat-autocomplete.

HTML code below:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search......." aria-label="Number" style="text-transform: uppercase"
    matInput formControlName="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption (optionSelected)=getSelectedClient($event.option);>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of displayList; let i = index" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to get the index of the selected item.

please help me!

Comment: I think this could work (I haven't tried it yet though):
Try to send the row via getSelectedClient, something like this: 
(optionSelected)=getSelectedClient($event.option, row)
 and adjust your function accordingly.

Comment: what is row here????

Comment: @Santhosh Have added an answer, check once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` event on Mat-Option

Replace your `mat-option` with:

```
<mat-option (click)="onSelect(option,i)" *ngFor="let option of displayList; let i = index" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

in TS file:

```
onSelect(value,index) {
  console.log('value --> ',value) // Value
  console.log('index --> ',index) // Index that you need
}
```

[A Working StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4eiqr)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo with option's index selected](https://angular-material-autocomplete-index-select.stackblitz.io/)**

You have to map the value of the index variable,
 `let i = index` to the value of the option in the `autocomplete` component.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" 
autoActiveFirstOption 
(optionSelected)="selectedOption($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of displayList; let i = index" [value]="i">
                    {{option}}
            </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

In component file:

```
selectedOption(event) {
   const selectedValue = event.option.value;
   console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

**Demo Application Code:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-index-select?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html

Please comment, if this is not the required case.

Comment: we already implemented this, but i have not to show the index in input box, after selecting the item from autocomplete box

Comment: @Santhosh okay, because `value` on the `mat-option` is responsible for that and through event, that only value is achievable. So mapping like this ` *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async, let i=index" [value]="state">` will result in whole `state` object, so either keep an extra key in state object that will hold the index.

Comment: it will not work, please provide any predefined event for mat-option in angular material api